# My D4 visa was rejected by the Embassy of Portugal in New Delhi

Tags: visa-refusals, portugal

I submitted my visa application to the Portuguese Embassy in New Delhi. Today, the Portuguese Embassy in New Delhi sent me a notice of a prior hearing, which stated that "the applicant's English language level is inadequate for this program."

In addition, they gave me 10 working days to appeal the decision. I don't have an IELTS or TOEFL certificate; I only have an MoI. Is there any possibility of getting the visa if I appeal?

Comment: If the eligibility criteria require IELTS/TOEFLand you don’t meet that criteria, then I do not see any possibility of an appeal succeeding